# Expose WCF service to asmx client and WCF client

Tags: wcf, xml-serialization, asmx, datacontract

We have a WCF service that has operations which receive a `List` of data contract objects as their parameter and return a `List` of different data contract objects eg.

```
List<CheckOutResponse> ProcessCheckOut(List<CheckOutRequest> obj);
```

This service is currently being consumed by a WCF client and it works great.

We now need to expose the same service to a legacy application built on .NET 1.1. I understand the binding changes that I need to make in the service's `web.config`, use the `basicHttp` binding and set the correct service behavior etc.

My problem is the data contracts. I believe that the .NET 1.1 clients use the `XMLSerializer` and this cannot work with data contracts.

I really don't want to change the data contracts to some other .NET 1.1 compatible complex types because we'd then need a load of regression testing with the existing WCF client.

Has anyone worked out a solution to this problem?

Comment: Use the `basicHttpBinding` for your ASMX clients - in the end, the messages are serialized into SOAP (XML) messages on the wire, and the .NET 1.1 ASMX client will deserialize that with whatever tools/algorithms/libraries it has available to it (it doesn't know nor care where that SOAP message came from)

Answer (score 2):

There should be no problem with the serialization. The .NET 1.1 client will simply see a structure that places the values into elements instead of attributes.